# Having an error in uploading file using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, filereader

When I am Uploading a file using the FileReader library the first time it's uploaded on the first click but the second time it is uploaded when I click on the button second time I am attaching a video link in which you can see the problem and attaching the code as well.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OzJLCA7URBcRy_5m_QVWAiLzo8l9eoqd/view

```
const imgPreviewing = (selected) => {
  let img = myImgElement
  if (selected.files && selected.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
      let src = reader.result;
      img.setAttribute("src", src);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(selected.files[0]);
  }
};
```

Thank You.

Comment: where are you *uploading* anything? The code you posted doesn't upload, it merely takes the selected file and uses it as the `src` attribute for "myImgElement" - uploading requires a POST request to your server - so there needs to be code both in the browser to upload it, and in the server to accept the upload - [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (a Web API - it's not a library, it's built in to every modern browser) is completely irrelevant to uploading

Comment: I am uploading img just by adding src I have added img element without src in HTML and now I am adding src to it so it will display the img. So what to use instead of FileReader any suggestion ?

Comment: uploading to where